# How to update Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID\{ID} Value

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, group-policy, windows-server-2016

does anyone know how to change/ update Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLID{ID} value>? I use the following PowerShell binding to Group Policy for updating certain registry key in HKCR when user login to the Domain but cannot work well. Actually, Try to perform this in the windows server 2016, everything works well. if the PowerShell was triggered by GPO, cannot work well. because it is weird PowerShell will be triggered once. when the client re-login to the Domain, the PowerShell will not be triggered. After that I separate the PowerShell to two files. it turns out that the first one was triggered, another one never be triggered. I have no idea the problem is GPO problem or PowerShell problemThanks

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
         $acl = Get-Acl $_DefaultOneDriveFromExplorerRegPath
         $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("litwareinc\Administrator","FullControl","Allow")
         $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
         $acl |Set-Acl -Path $_DefaultOneDriveFromExplorerRegPath
        
         Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_DefaultOneDriveFromExplorerRegPath -Name System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree -Value 0
```

Comment: So what line does the script fail on exactly?  You can use breakpoints to determine this.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of submitting temporary comment.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, Try to perform this in the windows server 2016, everything works well. if the PowerShell was triggered by GPO, cannot work well. because it is weird PowerShell will be triggered once. when the client re-login to the Domain, the PowerShell will not be triggered. After that I separate the PowerShell to two files. it turns out that the first one was triggered, another one never be triggered. I have no idea the problem is GPO problem or PowerShell problem.

Comment: What policy setting are you using to launch this? Since this change requires administrator permissions, make sure that it is not set to `run as current user` and is not set as a login script

Comment: I create a ourselves GPO. and the script locates in the path is "Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)" and the exaction account is system account. the script will be triggered first time to setup some registries. Second time, when user restart and login, it should be triggered once again to detect if the registries has been done, if yes, we will update other registries.